# Twitter Bootstrap Response Time (Little Confused)

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in the process of making a project (website) and I needed some advice. My plan is to use NodeJS with the express webframework. I want to make this website really user friendly and nice just like everyone wants their website to be. The problem is that I might not be the most artistic meaning what I might think is artistic might actually not be artistic. My plan was to use Twitter bootstrap but I was scared of the response time of my website if I use bootstrap on my website. I feel like it might slow the response time of my website.

Is this true? Should I just stick to CSS + HTML to make it unique on my own or are there any other frameworks?

Thanks

Comment: Think you might be slightly confused about bootstrap. it is just html and css (well really its just css and you add the html you want. you only need js components to use the functionality like sliders and dropdowns, everything else is css

Comment: Just remove the unnecessary components from [`bootstrap.less`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/e213bc0cccf236243210830626c415be48aed6f1/less/bootstrap.less) when compiling Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If You add Twitter Bootstrap Framework from CDN, for example: http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ there is a chance that people around web will have it cached by browser. But still, this framework is big (a lot of kB) and imho:

**Pros:**

- maintenance is easy (complex documentation), so if You work in team with many people, it's easier to do it with any kind of framework
- Bootstrap is large but customizable. You can get only some of JS plugins, and if You disable (for example in LESS version) some CSS stuff, it will be smaller
- it's popular - cache advantage

**Cons:**

- List item
- big size and can affect page speed time

Comment: That's what I'm a little scared about Michael. The big size will def affect the page speed time. At the same time, I'm not sure if I feel confident in my artistic abilities to make the website user friendly. Is there any other way around it or do I just have to dive in experimenting with CSS?

Comment: Do You have any idead how fast website do You want to develop?:) I know the right answer: the fastest it's possible; but maybe You have any numbers on your mind.

Comment: Honestly, I just want it to run smoothly without any type of delay or slow response. Don't have much numbers in my mind atm though

Comment: IMHO if You worry about your artistic abilities, use Bootstrap. But let's try to customize it as deep as possible. Making completley unfriendly website for user will scare them more than 0,5s slower website.